# Airflow - task fail without log

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a pipeline that start with by getting a file in a GCS bucket and do several tasks on it.

Sometime, after big update I have to rerun every file one by one. That's what I did and everything goes well for 190 files (for around 290 in total) but suddenly on task fail, without log. This task should have launch a K8s pod but here nothing. No logs in airflow, no pod launched in K8s. If I try to clear the task but still fail the same way.

The task fail as soon as lunched. I restarted the instance, I have space on the disk... I have no idea what to do.

Comment: It is possible that it hit a try catch block and thus didn't raise the error message that would trigger a fail state.

Comment: Just my disk full of scheduler logs... :(